# What does the term efficiency mean when talking about quantum memories?

Tags: terminology-and-notation, quantum-memory

Lots of papers about quantum memories talk about the efficiency generally or the storage/retrieval efficiency as a figure of merit. What exactly does this term mean?

My intuition would be that it would be related to the fidelity between the state that goes into the memory and the state that comes out, since I would have thought that was the most important figure of merit, but the same papers also talk about fidelity, so it can't be that. And why is it important that it is high?

My understanding of quantum memory is that you want to store a state for a long time with little decoherence, but that seems to only depend on the fidelity.

Comment: Page 7 of the following paper seems to define the two quantities: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.03123.pdf

Comment: Thanks! So then storage/retrieval efficiency is the probability that the state even gets stored in the first place (as opposed to being consumed without being stored, I assume), and the fidelity they give is IF it gets correctly stored in the first place?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right.   Admittedly I am not that acquainted with this subfield, but with memories I can imagine two different scenarios.  (1) No photons are lost during storage and retrieval, but the memory itself is faulty, so $\eta=1$ but the fidelity is bad.  On the other hand, (2) the memory could be great at not corrupting your data, but wait too long, and you can only retrieve your data with some low probability.   These are two independent metrics we might care about.